# Unravel the string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

How to unravel the string with the list of words provided.

For example:

```
List of words in Dictionary:

Hi
Hello
Welcome
to
Stack
Overflow

Input String:

WelcometoStackOverflow

Output must be (with space added):

Welcome to Stack Overflow
```

For the words not present in the list, `NULL` should be printed.

```
Input String:

StackOverflowWelcomeYou

Output must be:

NULL
```

Any suggestions or ideas how to implement...??

Comment: Firstly, please decide on the language. Secondly, please demonstrate some effort by attempting to do this yourself and posting the code you've got.

Comment: Third, describe the problem more precisely.

Comment: Can input be assumed to be in camel case (starting with upper case letter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biggest challenge is how to break-up the input string and all the answers/comments will be based on some assumption until OP provides more details.

In this answer *assumption is that input is a camel case string with first letter upper case*.

```
public class CheckDict {
    static Set<String> dict = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] 
                              {"Hi", "Hello", "Welcome", "To", "Stack", "Overflow"}));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test 1: " + findDict("WelcomeToStackOverflow"));
        System.out.println("Test 2: " + findDict("StackOverflowWelcomeYou"));
    }

    static String findDict(String str) {
        // split the string when we encounter an upper case letter except at start
        String[] arr = str.split("(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])");
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(arr[0]);
        for (int i=1; i< arr.length; i++) {
            if (!dict.contains(arr[i]))
                return null;
            else
                output.append(' ').append(arr[i]);
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Test 1: Welcome To Stack Overflow
Test 2: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach I would take to solve the algorithm.

1) Load in the Dictionary into a hash map structure for ammortized constant time lookup, or into an ordered map for logarithmic time look up

2) iterater through the possible substrings [0, i] until a match is found in the dictionary

a) if a match is found remove this word from the input string and store in an ArrayList structure for reporting the final answer

b) if a match is not found or i is equal to the size of the string report null

3) Iterate over your array list of strings and print a space separated list

Depending on the lookup time, which we call L this algorithm should take O(n * L) where n is the number of characters in the input string. if the lookup takes ammortized constant time, e.g., a hash map then it will be O(n) otherwise you could do it in O(n log D). where D is the size of the dictionary.